# Hiding custom UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have successfully created and implemented a custom `UITabBarController` with a custom `UITabBar` following [this tutorial](http://www.rumex.it/2011/07/hiding-your-new-custom-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application/). It works fine until I have to hide it.

I'm not using Storyboards or IB and I have to get a reference to my existing `UITabBarController` which is on screen to hide a custom `UIView` in it. I'm trying to do it this way but it's only creating a new instance of that `UITabBarController` and not pointing me to the original instance I see onscreen:

```
SGTabBarController *tabBarController = [[SGTabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController hideCustomTabBar];
```

**SGTabBarController.h**

```
@interface SGTabBarController : UITabBarController

@property (nonatomic) int tabBarHeight;

-(void)hideCustomTabBar;
-(void)showCustomTabBar;

@end
```

**SGTabBarController.m**

```
-(void)hideCustomTabBar{
    customTabBarView.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"HIDDEN!!!");
}

-(void)showCustomTabBar{
    customTabBarView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Any ideas on how to get to it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you setting the tabBarController to the rootViewController in AppDelegate? I programmatically do that and am able to access the tabBarController whenever needed.

Comment: @TheJer Make it an answer and I'll accept it! Awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I am able to access a custom UITabBarController anywhere in the app.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Set up the Dashboard
//
_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *tabBarItems = [@[] mutableCopy];

// Repeat this for any amount of ViewControllers
UITableViewController *tableViewController = [UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UINavigationController *navController = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];

[tabBarItems addObject:navController];
tabBarController.viewControllers = tabBarItems;
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;

return YES;
}
```

Comment: Great one! Just what I needed!